# What are the required headers of x-kernel

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

I am reading a book, Computer Networks - A Systems Approach by Davie and Peterson. Some of its example codes refer to types and functions, which according to my web search, are part of "x-kernel":

- evSchedule
- evCancel
- semWait
- semSignal
- msgAddHdr
- msgSaveCopy
- msgStripHdr
- msgDestroy

I would like to know, what header files and libraries I need to include in order to compile the code. I am also interested in whether x-kernel is still in use, and what its alternatives are.

Comment: I have never heard of this before. It sounds like a library that was developed specifically for the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this: https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/projects/xkernel/software.html

> The x-kernel is an object-based framework for implementing network protocols. It defines an interface that protocols use to invoke operations on one another (i.e., to send a message to and receive a message from an adjacent protocol) and a collection of libraries for manipulating messages, participant addresses, events, associative memory tables (maps), threads, and so on.
>
> [...]
>
> The x-kernel is also used in computer network courses to give students hands-on experience with network protocols. Information about a new textbook that uses the x-kernel to illustrate networking concepts--- Computer Networks: A Systems Approach.

It looks like it hasn't been updated since 1998.

As for what headers you need, there's a download link that has 54 header files in /include/. I bet that's what you need. I can find some, but not all of the functions you list in those headers.

As for what people use now - the book seems really broad, covering everything from 4B5B to public key encryption, so I don't think there's any single equivalent.